# Reading JSON array into UITableView on iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is the code in my `ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@end
```

And here is the `ViewController.m`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"News";

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/external/search?query=hello"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    news = [responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As far as I can tell, the code that puts the JSON into the dictionary is wrong, as it is trying to find an index which does not exist.  Is there a way to change this code so that it can read an array of JSON into the dictionary instead?

**Update: Here is the new code in my .m file:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"News";

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/external/search?query=hello"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
    //news = [responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
    // [mainTableView reloadData];
    if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        news = responseDict;
        [mainTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Error.");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

NSString *_getString(id obj)
{
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? obj : nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"]);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: please NSlog the `responseDict `

Comment: If `responseDict` is `nil`, make a string of `data` and log it.

Comment: The JSON seems to be missing a closing ] character, or is that a typo? Also it looks like an array of 3 NSDictionaries. Normally, a full JSON would include { } as the root e.g. { [{ dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3}] }

Comment: Why are you only using one element of the array??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
news = [responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
```

to

```
news = responseDict;
```

in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method.

**Update:**

```
/* -viewDidLoad, just fix warning "unused var" */
// [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

-

```
/* connectionDidFinishLoading */
// NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
//news = [responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
// [mainTableView reloadData];
if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        news = responseDict;
        [mainTableView reloadData];
} else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Error.");
}
```

-

```
NSString *_getString(id obj)
{
        return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? obj : nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        // ...

       // cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"];
       // cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

        /** Your JSON value maybe NSNull */
        cell.textLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"]);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: So this would successfully load the table view data?

Comment: @Someone According to his code above，the tableView shows the whole JSON data from server, but he made a mistake that just put the first element of the JSON data to the variable `news`. Additionally, `new` is a NSArray type, but the `[responseDict objectAtIndex:0]` is a NSDictionary

Comment: Not loading the table view.

Comment: @Witch-King your NSURLConnection should be "retain"ed, you may define a var in @interface or use `[NSURLConnection connectionWIthURL...]`

Comment: With the edits, this still isn't working.  I have updated the code I am currently using.

Comment: @Witch-King Maybe somewhere else was wrong, you can test my code with creating a new project, then add an `UITableViewController` subclass as the `appDelegate.window.rootViewController`, paste my code to your UITableViewController, replace `mainTableView` with `self.tableView`